# ローカルに配置した HTA から HTMLを起動する際に、二重起動を抑止することは可能でしょうか？

Tags: javascript, html, windows, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

端末上のローカルでhtaからhtmlを起動させるのですが、htmlが二重で起動できないよう制御したいと考えています。

以下のような案を考えていますが、目標達成に向けアドバイスいただけないでしょうか？
もしくは、これ以外に目標達成できる案をご存知でしたら教えていただけないでしょうか？

①
hta(HTMLアプリケーション）からhtmlをEdgeで起動するため、ActiveXで以下のように起動しています。

```js
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("\"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe\" \"" + 遷移先URL + "\"");
```

下記の参考ページのような形で起動制御をしたいのですが、Runメソッドによる起動でも、ウィンドウオブジェクトを生成できないでしょうか。

参考サイト：
[ウィンドウの２重起動を防止したい - 教えて!goo](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/602290.html)

②
①の参考サイトのように起動制御をするために、window.openを使って、htaファイルからhtmlをEdgeで開くことはできないでしょうか。（htaはIEに依存しているため、window.openではIEが開かれてしまいます）

③
htaからhtmlを起動する際に二重起動制御を加えるのではなく、開かれる側のhtmlで画面起動時、既にhtmlファイルが起動していたら閉じる。といった方法があればご教示いただきたいです

Answer (score 2):

管理下のEdgeのみで運用するなら[Prevent Duplicate Tabs](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/prevent-duplicate-tabs/iijplllphnkkeepcinimpjobncicbbmb)というaddonを利用すると、同一アドレスのタブが重複したら閉じることができるようです。